# {this.props.PROP} within a ClassName .- ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have next code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title text-center" style={STYLES.titleStyle}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> {this.props.title}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style={STYLES.contentStyle}>
        {children}
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want try to do this: (See glyphicon, line 3)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title text-center" style={STYLES.titleStyle}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{this.props.MY-ICON}"></span> {this.props.title}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style={STYLES.contentStyle}>
        {children}
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this?. If so... How could I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually have something like the following in my projects where I use icons

(the following is for Font Awesome, but just change `fa` to `glyphicons` and it'll be more or less correct)

```
export const Icon = (props: IconComponentProps) => {
    return <i className={ `fa fa-${props.icon} ${props.className}` } />;
};
```

You use it like

```
<Icon icon="check" className="green" />
```

producing

`<i class="fa fa-check green"></i>`

if you don't want to go that far and only really want it to work in this specific case, just pass an `myIcon` prop to the containing component and use `` className={ `glyphicon glyphicon-${this.props.myIcon}`} ``